# Connecting power bi to Azure data lake gen 2

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-lake-gen2

[image]

Hey everyone I am trying to connect Powerbi to my data lake gen 2 on azure I am set as
Storage Blob Data Contributor Aswell as Storage Blob Data Reader on the Storage account level i am not sure if I am doing something wrong but I also used the MS docs yet nothing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/datalakestorage

The URL is formatted according to this format https://.dfs.core.windows.net//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve `Access to the resource is forbidden` error, try following ways:

- As suggested by [Etienne Oosthuysen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac5e22d5-7a72-4e74-830c-93d680d5e12f/trying-to-access-my-storage-account-errors-with-quotaccess-to-the-resource-is-forbiddenquot?forum=windowsazuredata), check the date-time settings of your system.

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/datalakestorage#subfolder-or-file-not-supported-in-power-query-online):

- Only this format is supported `https://<accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container>`
- It doesn't support filename or subfolder like this,`https://<accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container>/<filename>` or `https://<accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container>/<subfolder>`

You can refer to [Get Data from Azure Data Lake Gen 2 : Access to the resource is forbidden](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Get-Data-from-Azure-Data-Lake-Gen-2-Access-to-the-resource-is/m-p/758588)

Answer (score 0):

After disabling both Enable soft delete for blobs and containers in azure storage account connection issue was resolved.

To Change Settings
Go To Azure storage account ---> Data Protection--->Disable soft delete for blobs/Enable soft delete for containers

[image: Reference image]